# Can someone explain how this piece of code works its on an upcoming test

Tags: loops, variables, while-loop

Can someone please explain to me the result of this code

I got the answer -8 from running the code but don't understand how you get it

```
int a = 16, b = 8, c = 0;
while((a >= 0) && (b != 0))
{
    if (a<b) {
        a=a-b; 
    } else {
        b=b + a; 
    }
    if(a==0) {
        c=b; 
    } else {
        c=a; 
    }
}
System.out.println(c);
```

**output:** -8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it makes 2 loops. This is the initial state:

1. values: `{a=16, b=8, c=0}`

Now lets get inside the first loop where `a > b`, so

2. values: `{a=16, b=24, c=16}`

Last loop where `a < b`, so

3. values: `{a=-8, b=24, c=-8}`

then `c=-8`. Thats why the output is -8.